# Get current user's starred playlist or library and tracks/artists

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

I've researched this a fair amount and wasn't able to find anything addressing this specific topic.

I want to get all the artists in the current user's library or even just out of a specific playlist, like the '*starred*' playlist.

When I try to get into the artists or tracks in a playlist, I get `'undefined'` back.

**Am I doing something wrong?**

Here's some basic javascript I'm using to display the library object and all I get back is what's in the image, but I don't know how to get into individual tracks and artists.  Any help?

```
require(['$api/models','$api/library'], function(models, library){
    'use strict';
    var Library = library.Library.forCurrentUser();
    console.log(Library.starred);
});
```

Here is an image of the model i'm getting back:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY3pT.png

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly more complicate than that. `Library.starred` is a [`Playlist`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-playlist.html) object that lazy loads the attributes. Thus, you need to pass what attributes you want to load, in this case `tracks`. Since tracks is a [Collection](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-collection.html) you then need to perform a [Snapshot](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-snapshot.html) and once you have the tracks you need to specify what attributes to load from the tracks.

Here is the code to fetch all the tracks from your starred playlist and print out their name and uri:

```
require(['$api/models','$api/library'], function(models, library){
    'use strict';
    var Library = library.Library.forCurrentUser();
    Library.starred.load('tracks').done(function(playlist) {
        playlist.tracks.snapshot().done(function(tracks) {
            var promises = [];
            // we fetch all the tracks
            for (var i = 0, l = tracks.length; i < l; i++) {
                var track = tracks.get(i);
                // fetch the information we need from the tracks
                // e.g. uri and name
                promises.push(track.load('uri', 'name'));
            }

            models.Promise.join(promises).done(function(tracksPromises) {
                tracksPromises.forEach(function(tp) {
                    console.log(tp.uri + ' - ' + tp.name);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  The Spotify API documentation is really confusing to me.  I've worked with other APIs but it isn't really clear how a lot of the methods and stuff tie together and the snapshot thing was the last place I would've thought to look for this.  Regardless, thank you very much for your help (would upvote you but I need more rep, heh)

Comment: One last thing i'm confused on is how to get the 'release' year for an album or set of albums.  I've been able to get all the URIs for all the albums in my library but I mostly just want the release year of the album.  I know the lookup requests do it but what about within the spotify desktop client API?

Comment: The release year is not exposed per se. A workaround is fetching the `copyrights` property and try to extract a year from there.